Text data labeling
Task: Classify customer emails into relevant categories based on their content.
Data: DataFrame containing customer emails.
I have a dataset of customer emails stored in a data frame. Each email pertains to a specific issue the customer encountered. My goal is to categorize these emails automatically. For example, an email about problems with food quality would be categorized as "Food Quality Issue," while an email regarding payment difficulties would be categorized as "Payment Issue."
The challenge lies in the unknown number of potential categories. There could be a vast range of issues customers might contact us about.
My plan is to address this challenge in two steps:

Data Labeling: I need to  label a representative sample of emails from the data frame. This labeling process involves assigning each email a category that accurately reflects the customer's concern.
Classifier Model Training: Once I have a labeled dataset, I can use it to train a machine learning model. This model will then be able to automatically categorize new, unseen emails based on the patterns it learns from the labeled data.
I need answer for first part , how can i label data.

My approach was to generate embeddings of email and then apply clustering,but result is not good.
Please help me to solve this problem and is any thing to apply before generating embeddings.

That seems like a reasonable approach to this problem. Is there a specific aspect of that you'd like help with?

How about using an LLM and let it label your data? A clustering approach will only be sufficient when you use a model that produces valuable semantical sentence embeddings.

I've been trying an approach where I take a sample of 100 emails and ask a large language model (LLM) to categorize them. Once a category is created, I include it in subsequent calls. The LLM then checks if the new email belongs to any existing category and assigns it if so. Otherwise, it creates a new category. However, I'm encountering two issues:

The LLM tends to create too many categories.
After processing 300-400 emails, the LLM starts providing inaccurate responses.


I've been trying an approach where I take a sample of 100 emails and ask a large language model (LLM) to categorize them. Once a category is created, I include it in subsequent calls. The LLM then checks if the new email belongs to any existing category and assigns it if so. Otherwise, it creates a new category. However, I'm encountering two issues:

The LLM tends to create too many categories.
After processing 300-400 emails, the LLM starts providing inaccurate responses.


You can try multiple things:

Try LDA model
use GPT API to label your data. For email kind of thing it will give you good result without the need of fine tunning. And if you are not worried about your data getting used by gpt then you can try free gpt as well for this.
Clustering should work if there is pattern in your data. Share the issue that you are facing during the clustering.
This is very naive approch. But what you can do is try to remove stop words. then create bigram and unigram of each words. and visualize them and most likely you will know the label names. then you can do the manual labelling of the data because you will know the label name already.

